# Как реализовать верстку изогнутого блока?

Tags: вёрстка

Как сверстать такой блок, а точнее эту изогнутую шапку на блоке?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: png будет гора-а-аздо быстрее и проще )) но можно, конечно, поизвращаться с css3 и всякими псевдоэлементами

Comment: Если это не принципиально важно именно сверстать - поддержу того, который сверху. Юзай `png`, даже если сверстаешь такую штуку - с адаптивностью будет долго и скучно.

Comment: @Klimenkomud картинкой похоже не получится, потому что этот блок в макете не идет отдельным слоем, и их много разных цветов и т. д., так что похоже что нужна таки верстка, а на счет адаптации не страшно оно находится в контейнере бутсрапа, там сам блок-wrap адаптивно сдвинется

Comment: @humster_spb а может svg лучше будет? )

Comment: @Croessmah, без сомнения :))

Answer (score 14, accepted):

С размерами можно поиграться, но идея примерно такая:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.dot {
  position: absolute;
  width: 17px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.dot.right {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.lorem {
  position: absolute;
  width: 280px;
  height: 150px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, white, silver);
  top: 10px;
  left: -40px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px silver;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding-top: 120px;
}

.step {
  position: absolute;
  width: 166px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: gray;
  top: 0;
  left: 17px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.romb {
  position: absolute;
  left: 63px;
  top: 53px;
  width: 74px;
  height: 74px;
  background-color: gray;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) skew(30deg, 30deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="dot left"></div>
  <div class="dot right"></div>
  <div class="lorem">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  <div class="step">ШАГ 1</div>
  <div class="romb"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: отлично, спасибо большое!

Comment: в этом решении три лишних элемента: dot left, dot right и romb. Для этих целей нужно использовать `:before` и `:after`.

Comment: @cronfy, где написано, что "нужно"?

Answer (score 6):

Какой png? Простые вещи разучились делать...

```css
:root {
  --sizeFillets: 20px;
  --widthLabel: 200px;
  --heightLabel: 150px;
  --colorLabel: grey;
  --colorShadow: black;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  margin: auto;
  width: var(--widthLabel);
  height: var(--heightLabel);
  background-color: var(--colorLabel);
  position: relative;
}

div::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-width: var(--sizeFillets) calc(var(--widthLabel)/2) 0 calc(var(--widthLabel)/2);
  border-top-color: var(--colorLabel);
}

span {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  left: calc(var(--sizeFillets)/-2);
  top: calc(var(--sizeFillets)/-2);
  width: calc(100% + var(--sizeFillets));
  height: calc(var(--sizeFillets)/2);
  background-color: var(--colorLabel);
}

span::after,
span::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(var(--sizeFillets)/-2);
  width: var(--sizeFillets);
  height: calc(var(--sizeFillets)/2);
  border-radius: var(--sizeFillets) var(--sizeFillets) 0 0;
  background-color: var(--colorShadow);
}

span::after {
  left: calc(100% + var(--sizeFillets)/-2);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: а скошенные углы внизу где?

Comment: а разве вопрос был про это? мне показалось у автора проблемы с закруглением...

Comment: ребятам, которые предлагали правки. отклонено, потому что размеры в пикселях, а нужно на css-переменных сделать.

Answer (score 5):

Предложу свой вариант.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
.badge {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, white, silver);
  padding: 5rem 1rem 1rem;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 50;
}
/* Левый и правый изгибы */
.badge:before,
.badge:after {
  content: '';
  width: 17px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  background: #000;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}
/* Позиция левого изгиба */
.badge:before {
  left: 48px;
}
/* Позиция правого изгиба */
.badge:after {
  right: 48px;
}
.badge__flag {
  background: gray;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin: auto 4rem;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #eee;
  padding: 1rem;
}
/* Нижняя и верхняя части стрелки */
.badge__flag:before,
.badge__flag:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
}
/* Верхняя часть стрелки */
.badge__flag:before {
  top: -10px;
  left: -5%;
  width: 110%;
  height: 10px;
  background: gray;
  z-index: -5;
}
/* Нижняя часть стрелки */
.badge__flag:after {
  bottom: -15px;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 15px solid gray;
  border-left: 94px solid transparent;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="badge">
  <p class="badge__flag">Шаг 1</p>
  <p class="badge__copy">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  </p>
</div>
```